# Existence of the centre of mass of a measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, proof-verification, solution-verification

> Let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb R^n$ with compact
>   support. Show that there exists $b \in \mathbb R^n$, the centre of
>   mass of $\mu$, such that $$b \cdot v = \frac{\int x \cdot v\,  d\mu
>  (x)}{\mu(\mathbb R^n)} \ \ \ \text{for every $v \in \mathbb R^n$}$$

Here is my attempt at the problem. Apologies for the edit from the earlier version.

As $\mu$ is a finite measure we know that $M_1:=\mu(\mathbb{R}^n)<\infty$. The compact support means that $x$ is bounded on the support of $\mu$ and is therefore integrable, ie $\int x \, d\mu(x)<\infty$ and we therefore we obtain that $M_2 := \int x \cdot v \, d\mu(x) \ <\infty$. Now we note that for every $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there will exists a $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $a \cdot v=M_2$. So, by dividing by $M_1$ we obtain
    \begin{equation}
 \frac{a \cdot v}{M_1}= \left( \int x \cdot v \ d\mu(x) \right)\bigg/ M_1 = \left( \int x \cdot v \ d\mu(x) \right)\bigg/ \mu(\mathbb{R}^n)=
 \end{equation}
    so by setting $b=\frac{a}{M_1}$ we obtain our required result.

I am concerned that this is not water tight enough.

If it is incorrect I would appreciate hints as to how it can be done/improved.

Comment: The compact support means that $x$ is bounded on the support of $\mu$ (and hence integrable).

Comment: @1234 I think there's a nontrivial problem with sentence "Now we note that for every $v \in \mathbb R^n$ there will exists a $a \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $a \cdot v = M_2$." It seems to me that you're only claiming that an $a$ exists per each $v$, which would be insufficient: You need a single $a$ that works simultaneously for all $v$.

Comment: @epimorphic Ah thats a good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $b = \mu(\mathbb{R}^n)^{-1} \int x \, d\mu(x)$ (componentwise), then the statement follows directly from the linearity of the integral.

(Note: The original solution was more complicated, this follows the suggestion by Giuseppe Negro in the comments.)

Comment: Is it that complicated? Couldn't we just define $b_i=\int x_i \mu(dx_1\ldots dx_n)$? (assuming that the total mass of $\mu$ is one, of course)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro. of course you are right, not sure why I went the complicated route...